# ckeditor how to save image on server side

Tags: spring-mvc, ckeditor, image-uploading

I use ckeditor on my web, and want to edit some chapter with images, but I find it is hard to use ckeditor to upload image form local computer. I refer to this sample [ckeditor upload image](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/fileupload.html#uploading-dropped-and-pasted-images), and my question is how can I get the image file when I click the `send it to server` button on `upload` tab. I also don't know how to return to image url after `send it to server` successfully.

I use spring boot spring mvc and hibernate on my server side. I hope anyone can help me to post the server side source code, or just give some relevant material is also Ok.

Comment: This plugin only gives you the client-side part. You will need to implement the server-side (java code) of what to do with the images that are being sent to the server...

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I even cannot find a sample about `server-side (java code)` on google. Sometime I even thing maybe no one use ckeditor.

Comment: ckeditor is one of the most used javascript editors that exists :)

Comment: Regarding what you are looking for - you have [ckfinder](https://cksource.com/ckfinder) which is a paid solution, and I just found [jckconnector](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jckconnector/) (which is for ckeditor#3, but maybe it will also work for #4.

Comment: but almost no one post their server side solution about image upload

Comment: ckeditor is a client-side javascript based library. what you are looking for is a server-side solution (and there are dozen of server-side languages). I really don't think it will make sense that ckeditor will come with all the server-side languages solutions (we are talking about asp/asp.net/c#/vb.net/php/perl/python/java/r/ruby/node and I'm sure there are more... and if you are talking about specific frameworks [like spring] the list is endless...)

Comment: As @Dekel explained, you need a different solution for each server language. You can find several ones at https://github.com/AlfonsoML/CKEditorUploader so pick the one that you understand better and rewrite it for your requirements. If you then send me that version I can share it for others (otherwise don't complain that there are no samples for your requirements)

Answer (score 1):

its very easy to implement lets see....

javascript code ::

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {
                filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/image/upload'
            });
            CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (e) {
                var dialogName = e.data.name;
                var dialogDefinition = e.data.definition;
                switch (dialogName) {
                    case  'image':
                        //dialogDefinition.removeContents('info');
                        dialogDefinition.removeContents('Link');
                        // dialogDefinition.removeContents('advanced');
                        break;
                }
            });
            $('#btn_publish').click(function () {
                alert(CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData());
            });
            $('#btn_clear').click(function () {
                CKEDITOR.instances.editor.setData('');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

html code::

```
<form method="post" action="#" th:action="@{/abc}" th:object="${abc}"
              enctype="multipart/form-data">
<textarea name="cont" id="editor" rows="10" cols="80" th:field="*{newsDescription}"></textarea>
            <button type="button" id="btn_publish">Show</button>
            <button type="button" id="btn_clear">Clear All</button>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
```

then go to spring java class its looks like :

```
@PostMapping("/image/upload")
public String upload(@RequestPart MultipartFile upload, @RequestParam(value = "CKEditorFuncNum") String callback, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(upload.getOriginalFilename());
    String sourceName = upload.getOriginalFilename();
    String sourceExt = FilenameUtils.getExtension(sourceName);
    File destFile;
    String destFileName;
    do {
        destFileName = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(8).concat(".").concat(sourceExt);
        destFile = new File(uploadPath.concat(destFileName));
    } while (destFile.exists());
    destFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    upload.transferTo(destFile);
    String imgUrl = request.getScheme().concat("://").concat(request.getServerName()).concat(":").concat(String.valueOf(request.getServerPort())).concat(uploadUri).concat(destFileName);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(");
    sb.append(callback);
    sb.append(",'");
    sb.append(imgUrl);
    sb.append("','image uploaded successfully!!')</script>");
    return sb.toString();
}
```